# How to execute AJAX calls in order in loop using Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I am looping through a map, where I want to make a separate AJAX call with each map value as parameter, to fetch some data and log it. See below. This is working, but I'd like to have the AJAX calls go in order of the map. Because each call is asynchronous, so seems like I should use promises to achieve execution in order. But I am new to promises and don't really know how to do it here. I have look elsewhere on here but could not find anything. Please help.

```
map.forEach(function(url, key) {
   log(url);
});

function log(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url, 
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
          console.log(result.value);
          console.log(result.name);
          console.log(result.action);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: since $.ajax returns an (almost) promise, promise chaining would be one way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $.ajax returns a promise, you can use promise chaining to achieve what you want

```
var p = $.when();
map.forEach(function(url, key) {
    p = p.then(function() { 
        return log(url);
    });
});

function log(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.value);
            console.log(result.name);
            console.log(result.action);
        }
    });
}
```

Note: the code above uses only jQuery, no native promises

Or using reduce function of Array

```
map.reduce(function(p, url) {
    return p.then(function() { 
        return log(url);
    });
}, $.when());
```

If you can use ES2015+, so have native Promises,

```
map.reduce((p, url) => p.then(() => log(url)), Promise.resolve());
```

If you wanted, you can also do it like this

```
function log(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

map.reduce((p, url) => p.then(results => log(url).then(result => results.concat(result))), Promise.resolve([]))
.then(results => {
    results.forEach(result => {
        console.log(result.value);
        console.log(result.name);
        console.log(result.action);
    })
});
```

The difference being as that all the console.log's would happen once the LAST request finished (and if any fail, none of the console log's would happen)

Comment: Or `.reduce()` to (arguably) pretty it up slightly.

Comment: this is great, can you explain how the JQuery way knows when to move to the next call?

Comment: it's how promises work ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises explains it better than I could

Comment: @JaromandaX how does it know that it hit success and not failure in AJAX? I read the link but could not understand

Comment: jquery ajax returns promise the resolves on success and rejects on failure ... you know what resolve and reject means with regards to promises?

Comment: @JaromandaX great example!, is there any documentation i can read on how to trigger a simple `alert("done");` when the loop is done running?  Currently if i put an alert after the forEach loop in ie11 the alert is displayed before the loop is intialized.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To chain promises should work:

```
function ajaxPromises(urls) {
  return Promise.all(urls.map(function(url) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url, 
      dataType: 'json'
    })
  }))
}
```

Usage:

```
ajaxPromises(['http://yoururl.com','http://yoururl.com'])
  .then(function (result) {
    // do something with result
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    //  do something with error
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you could use async/await syntax in your project, then nothing could be easier:

```
async function log(url) { 
  return await 
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result.value);
      console.log(result.name);
      console.log(result.action);
    });
}

async function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    await log(map[i]);
  }
}

run();
```

You see, I changed `forEach` to `for` loop. It's important for `await` usage, because it provides (instead of `forEach` and other callback based loops) synchronicity of async `log` calls.

**UPD** Here is [the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/618Bu22PCrZCgwG81VwK?p=preview) which demonstrates such an approach.

Comment: What is the advantage of async await vs. $.when()?

Comment: @user8571142 `$.when` is jQuery specific approach, which isn't relevant to all javascript world. Also, I like Jaromanda X's `reduce` solution, but `for` + `await` is much more readable. All magic is hidden under async/await implementation, which makes the async logic just looks like synchronous.