# for is adding i++ before performing an entire action, ajax async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, asynchronous

The problem is the following, I have an array, I perform a `for` that traverses this array and for each element inside the array it performs an AJAX request, and even though I put the `async: false` property, apparently it is still an asynchronous request, which does so that the variable `i` inside the for loops through everything and only performs the request on the last element of the array.

```js
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        let elemnt = array[i]
        console.log(i)
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: 'https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xx/'+elemnt,
            type: 'GET',
            success: (data)=>{
                //does something with array element...                   
                }
            })
        }
```

putting the `console.log(i)` was then to output:

```
    0
    *Perform AJAX request with array[0]*
    1
    *Perform AJAX request with array[1]*
    2
    *Perform AJAX request with array[2]*
```

however it stays:

```
    0
    1
    2
    *Perform AJAX request with array[2]*
```

I believe this is all due to Ajax's Asynchronous realization, but I already put `async: false`, I don't know what else it could be.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Comment: This willn't make the loop synchronous. either you should use  yourfunction.then(()=>{}) or use async/await

Comment: my guess is it is working there is an error and not a success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute AJAX calls in order in loop using Javascript Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214895/how-to-execute-ajax-calls-in-order-in-loop-using-javascript-promise)

Comment: I will analyze your answers, I will see if it solves my problem and thanks in advance. @epascarello, actually success, because testing each element but 1 at a time and that's how it works, the problem is when there's more than 1 element in the array.

Comment: I would add an error handler and prove it is not throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the array and running ajax in the loop, create a function that ONLY continues when ajax is successful.

In the below example, **cur** is the position in the array to grab the value from. For the ajax call, I shortened it just for my answer obviously you will need to use your full ajax.

```
let cur = 0;

function runAjax() {
  $.ajax({
    ......
    success: (data) => {
      if (cur == array.length) {
        console.log("Done!");
      } else {
        cur++;
        runAjax();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Or even simpler `await $.ajax()`. No need to reinvent the wheel. Although it's probably a good idea to also move the `success` handler to a `.then()`